# electron-react-boilerplate could not load dll plugin on `npm run package-win`

Tags: webpack, electron

The app that i'm working on is built on top of [`electron-react-boilerplate`](https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate).

I'm debugging for 2 days an issue regarding the loading of a dll plugin (pepflashplayer.dll)
The dll is being loaded in a file very similar to `main.dev.js` using this code:

```
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('ppapi-flash-path', path.join(__dirname+'//lib//', pluginName))
```

**The plugin is being loaded correctly in dev and prod mode**, but when the app is being packaged `"package-win": "npm run build && build --win --x64"`, **the plugin is not being loaded.**

I've taken the code apart and the problem is not in in the `main.dev.js` file.
I'm asking for your opinions since i'm a beginner in all of the technologies used.
Where do you think the problem is?

Answer (score -1):

Found this on the Github repo

> - Use Yarn instead of npm install
>
> There's a problem with npm install and the option to package
>   afterward. With yarn, you don't have this. I know it may be another
>   required technology, but we need to change the doc if we don't fix the
>   problem soon.
>
> (see issue #1065)

Can you check if that's causing the packaging issue.

Comment: Installed and packaged with yarn and the problem is the same.